# Multiple save operations in async.forEachOf

Tags: mongodb, async.js

I have a loop through some payments in a mongo collection. All the payments with payoutdate == today() must be exported and written to an sepa file, so we can handle the payments by bank.

The payments doesn't have an invoicenumber while they are created and we generating one when the payment is processed (exported via the above function).
The problem is, that when we run the function with multiple payments to be exported, all the payments are getting the same invoice number. So it looks like, that the last save operation is not completed before the next payment is processed.

How can I archieve that every payment is getting an increasing number?

## This is the loop function:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const async = require('async');
const DateDiff = require('date-diff');
const SEPA = require('sepa');
const shopService = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'services', 'shop.service'));

    async.forEachOf(payments, function(payment, key, paymentDone){            
        var diff = new DateDiff(new Date(payment.payoutDate), new Date());
        if(payment.payoutDate && payment.amount > 0 && payment.completed == false && payment.exported == false && diff.days() <= 0){
            //payment has amount, is not completed and is not exported, create an SEPA transfer, and set the payment to completed
            //but first create an invoicenumber

                orderService.updateOrderPayment(payment.orderId, {generateInvoiceNumber: true}, function(err, result){
                    if(err){
                        console.log("error updating payment", err);
                    }
                    //reget the payment to avoid duplicated invoice numbers

                    orderService.getPayment(result.orderId, function(err, payment){
                        if(err){
                            console.log("error getting payment", err);
                        }

                        Shop.findOne({_id: payment.shopId}).exec(function(err, shop){
                            if(shop && shop.bankAccountNumber && shop.accountHolder && shop.bicCode){
                               //create transaction and add this to the file
                            }else{
                                var result = {
                                    paymentID: payment._id,
                                    orderId: payment.orderId,
                                    status: payment.status,
                                    message: "shop does not have an iban, accountholder or biccode",
                                    shop: shop.nameSlug
                                }
                                resultArray.push(result);
                                console.log("shop does not have an iban, accountholder or biccode", shop.nameSlug);
                                paymentDone();
                            }

                            orderService.updateOrderPayment(payment.orderId, {status: 'completed'}, function(err, result){
                                orderService.updateOrderStatusById(payment.orderId, {status: 'Granted', date: new Date(), comment: null});
                                var result = {
                                    paymentID: payment._id,
                                    orderId: payment.orderId,
                                    status: payment.status,
                                    message: "payment exported",
                                }
                                resultArray.push(result);
                                counter++;
                                paymentDone();
                            })
                        })
                    })    
                })    
        }else{
            var result = {
                paymentID: payment._id,
                orderId: payment.orderId,
                status: payment.status,
                message: "order already processed"
            }
            resultArray.push(result);
            paymentDone();
        }
    }, function(){
        if(resultArray.length == payments.length){
            //console.log("Result", resultArray);
            if(counter == 0){
                res.status(200).json({"message":"No orders to export", resultArray});
            }else{
                res.set({"Content-Disposition":"attachment; filename=\"sepa.xml\""});
                res.send(doc.toString());
            }
        }
    })
```

## The orderService contains the following functions (relevant to this question)

```
function updateOrderPayment(orderId, paymentStatus, callback){
    console.log("updateOrderPayment");
    if(!paymentStatus){
        return callback("No payment details provided");
    }else{
        if(!paymentStatus.comment){
            paymentStatus.comment = null;
        }
    }
    getPayment(orderId, function(err, payment){
        if(err)
            return callback(err);

        handlePayment(payment, paymentStatus, function(result){
            result.save(function(err, result){
                if(err){
                    return callback(err);
                }
                console.log("payment saved");
                return callback(null, result);
            })
        })
    })
}

function handlePayment(payment, paymentStatus, callback){
    if(paymentStatus.status){
        var status = {
            status: paymentStatus.status,
            comment: paymentStatus.comment,
            date: Date.now()
        }
        payment.status.push(status);
    }

    if(paymentStatus.generateInvoiceNumber){
        console.log("generateInvoiceNumber");
        var invoiceNumber =0;

        Payment.findOne({invoiceNumber: {$exists:true}}).sort({_id: -1}).exec(function(err, latestPaymentsWithNumber){

            if(latestPaymentsWithNumber && latestPaymentsWithNumber.invoiceNumber){
                invoiceNumber = latestPaymentsWithNumber.invoiceNumber.split("-")[1];
            }

            var date = new Date();
            payment.invoiceNumber = date.getFullYear().toString() + date.getMonth().toString() + "-" + (parseInt(invoiceNumber)+1);
            console.log("number", payment.invoiceNumber);
            return callback(payment);
        })
    }

    if(paymentStatus.status == 'returned' || paymentStatus.status == 'cancelled'){
        payment.cancelled = true;
        payment.amount = 0;
        payment.payoutDate = null;
        return callback(payment);
    }

    if(paymentStatus.status == 'completed'){
        payment.completed = true;
        payment.exported = true;
        payment.payoutDate = null;  
        return callback(payment);
    }
}

function getPayment(orderId, callback){
    Payment.findOne({orderId: orderId}).exec(function(err, payment){
        if(err){
            return callback(err);
        }
        return callback(null, payment);
    })
}
```

Comment: you should be using series or waterfall .. async should be in a sequence or retain the scope until the operation's finished by implementing callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both of the reply's! A combination was the solution.

I have changed the query to find the last `invoiceNumber` to

```
Payment.find({invoiceNumber: {$ne:null}}).sort({date: -1}).limit(1).exec(function(err, latestPaymentsWithNumber){
```

I use now async.eachSeries to iterate over `payments`: 
`async.eachSeries(payments, function(payment, paymentDone)`{

And I do a result.save in the first callback to asume I have the right data

```
result.save(function(err, payment){
```

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 choices:

1) implement callbacks to your save operation within scope

```
x.forEach(function(_x) {
  _x.save(function(err) { });
});
```

2) break out your functions to async units or use an async library

```
function async(x, cb) {
  x.operations(cb)
}

function series(x) {
  if (x) {
    async(x, function() { series(xs.pop()); });
  } else // finished
}

series(xs.pop()); // xs is the array you're iterating
```